# White glow around UILabel and UIView when running on device

Tags: uiview, uilabel, tvos

When running my application on my Apple TV a white glow is added to my `UILabel` and `UIView`. Running my application on the simulator produces the results I expect, no glow. I suspected it was the `tint` property adding this white glow, but setting the `tint` property to `Clear Color` has not resolved my issue.

**Device** (White glow):

[image]

**Simulator** (Expected results, no glow):

[image]

Comment: Is this caused by the focus engine?

Comment: @Stefan no. The issue was created by my sharpness settings on my TV as suggested in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be your TV adding some contrast-enhancing or other sharpening effect. You should see if there's a way to disable that on your TV and that may make the effect go away.

Comment: Thank you @JustinVoss. Turns out it was the sharpness setting on my TV that was causing this. Turned it down to 0 and the white glow disappeared.